# Netbeans: Web app project do not see the namespace of my custom component, but everything work correct

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jsf-2, custom-component

I have my JSF custom component package as maven java application, inside my custom component, i have faces-config.xml and *taglib.xml inside my META-INF, but when I package it inside my maven webapp, netbeans does not see the namespace. However, everything work correctly (meaning my custom component render correctly). How can I fix it? Please see screenshot

[image]

If you look to the left, you can see my custom component tree structure (`InforSelect`), and to the right, you can see Netbeans complains about the `infor` namespace.

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, but just wanted to inform that Eclipse in its default trim has the same problem and that JBoss tools fixed it.